# Java Spring Boot: Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm working on a basic application using Java Spring Boot, I'm stuck on this error:

This is the error message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-16 12:44:40.321 ERROR 5698 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field userRepository in com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.SbcrashcourseApplication required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

1. My main class looks like this:

   ```
    package com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse;

    import com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.lendingengine.domain.model.User;
    import com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.lendingengine.domain.repository.UserRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.lendingengine"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.lendingengine.domain.repository")
    public class SbcrashcourseApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {SpringApplication.run(SbcrashcourseApplication.class, args);}

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        userRepository.save(new User(1, "John", "B", 27, "Software Developer"));
        userRepository.save(new User(2, "Peter", "C", 21, "Pilot"));
        userRepository.save(new User(3, "Henry", "E", 21, "Unemployed"));
    }
   ```

   }
2. UserRepository class is this:

   ```
   package com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.lendingengine.domain.repository;

    import com.htamayo.sbcrashcourse.lendingengine.domain.model.User;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    }
   ```
3. And my pom.xml looks like this:

   ```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

   org.springframework.boot
                  spring-boot-maven-plugin

I've been searching for solutions on Google but so far nothing, so my question is: I don't understand how to overcome the EntityManagerFactory error, am I missing a dependency? or should I refactor my code? any solutions?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you try simplifying your `pom.xml` file? Seems to me you're importing too many items -- and some of them are already included in the starter package of Spring.

See [this MySQL](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mysql/blob/main/initial/pom.xml) sample from Spring Data tutorial.

Comment: FOr starters your dependencies are a mess. Ditch all the hibernate dependencies. Remove the `spring-web` and `spring-webmvc` dependencies. On your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class remove `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Then restart your application using `--debug` to get more information and the stacktrace telling you what is wrong. You probably misconfigured your database.

Comment: thanks a lot, as a matter of fact, searching about this bug I started to add dependencies with no control and still the problem persist. I cleaned up my pom.xml and I will start the app in debug mode, I'll let you know what I get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after 17 days finally I got the solution:

my problem was on properties file, for some reason I used this line (I can't remember why):
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

I just commented it and problem solved.

Lessons learned:

1. always document your code
2. JitterTed's discord is a great source of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Issue : Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Resolution: After 3 days of struggle I found my problem was due to a property on properties file: spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

Post commented, at least this issue resolved.
I got another issue, which I will update soon.